# Unable to send the elastic metricbeat data to aws msk kafka cluster with sasl_ssl configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, aws-msk, metricbeat

I have created AWS MSK cluster with SASL_SSL authentication and able to send/receive the data to it by using python code. I am trying to integrate with Elastic Metricbeat output to Kafka with the below configurations and it is failing with:

```
 "**retryer: send unwait signal to consumer**" and also **Kafka publish failed with : circuit breaker is open**

'''
output.kafka:
enabled : true
hosts :["b-1.xxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com:9096",""b-2.xxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com:9096"]
topic: testtopic
username : username
password : password
sasl.mechanism : 'SCRAM-SHA-512'

partition.round_robin:
reachable_only: flase
codec.json:
pretty:true
escape_html:true

required_acks:1
compression: gzip
max_message_butes: 10000000
'''
```

I have tried with the above configuration. Please suggest me to resolve the issue. Thanks

Comment: You're missing some error information here. There should be more details about the reason for the failure i.e. Timeout, Unauthorised, Topic Doesn't Exist etc.

Comment: I think you're missing setting security.protocol to SASL_SSL also